# Rails activerecord possible delay with big tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have Message model which have like a tons of fields and around 10 million entries in the table.

Now i also have an SomeItem model which looks like this(it have just 1000 entries):

```
class SomeItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true # "Message" is one of the item types
end
```

now in have these two consecutive lines of code which bother me:

```
m = Message.new(:fild_one => 1, ...)
m.save
s = SomeItem.create(:item => m)
```

Now if see `m` is getting saved in the database fine at: `Sat, 05 Oct 2013 15:01:06 UTC +00:00` and `s` at `Sat, 05 Oct 2013 15:01:23 UTC +00:00` and thats fine.

but when i do:
`s.item_type it gives me "Message"` which is fine , but `s.id it gives me nil` in 3 out of 
 of 1000 entries.

So my question is:
Is there an kind of delay that prevents `m` created in the previous line to be used in the `s` created in the next line.

NOTE:
1) Message table is huge containing millions of entries

2) SomeItem table is small containing just 1000 of entries

3) As per me understanding rails execute these two sentences sequentially , but that does not explain this behavior.

Anyone noticed this before and if yes and if its a known thing what can be done to prevent this?

Thanks in advance. I understand the question looks silly , but its a real life scenario and is happening on my live project.

Comment: You wrote "but when i do: s.item_type it gives me "Meessage" which is fine , but s.id it gives me nil in 3 out of of 1000 entries." so if your s record havent id so it not done(maybe some validation not passed). Or maybe you mean s.item_id ? try make those scenario in console and next check s object validation like "s.valid?" and if false you can check why "s.errors.messages"

Comment: I dont have any validations on SomeItem currently and the `s` and `m` do get saved in the database , i picked up created_at time from the databse only.
Thanks.

Comment: By _"s.id it gives me nil in 3 out of of 1000 entries"_ do you mean out of 1000 records there are 3 that don't have ID or as in the instance of `SomeItem`. Also, if both object get saved to the database then what exactly is your problem?

Comment: my problem is 3 out of 1000 times rails behaves weirdly and not able to provide id of `m` instance created in the first line to the `s` instance in the next line, even though `m` is created and saved into the database with an id.

Comment: Odd… try add `!` to both `create` and `save` so it will throw an exception if it failed to save. I don't think it would be a thread issue but you never know… What version of ruby and rails you're using? Also you can type @ and handle name of a person you are replying to as well if you want that person to get notified.